# How to fix 'No such file or directory' error while loading MNIST dataset

Tags: python, python-3.x, mnist, mlxtend

I have downloaded the MNIST training images and labels from yann.lecun.com and unzipped them. I am trying to load them using this code-

```
from mlxtend.data import loadlocal_mnist

features,labels = loadlocal_mnist(
    images_path='/python/mnist-files/train-images-idx3-ubyte',
    labels_path='/python/mnist-files/train-labels-idx1-ubyte')
```

However, I get this error -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "generateClassifier.py", line 12, in <module>
    labels_path='/python/mnist-files/train-labels-idx1-ubyte')
  File "/home/inglorion/.local/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/mlxtend/data/local_mnist.py", line 36, in loadlocal_mnist
    with open(labels_path, 'rb') as lbpath:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/python/mnist- 
files/train-labels-idx1-ubyte'
```

The directory does exist, and the filenames are correct. How can I fix this?

EDIT: I tried the same with the `python-mnist` package-

```
from mnist import MNIST
mndata = MNIST('/python/mnist-files')
features,labels = mndata.load_training()
```

I got a similar error-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "generateClassifier.py", line 11, in <module>
    features,labels = mndata.load_training()
  File "/home/inglorion/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mnist/loader.py", 
line 126, in load_training
    os.path.join(self.path, self.train_lbl_fname))
  File "/home/inglorion/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mnist/loader.py", 
line 247, in load
    with self.opener(path_lbl, 'rb') as file:
  File "/home/inglorion/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mnist/loader.py", 
line 239, in opener
    return open(path_fn, *args, **kwargs)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/python/mnist- 
files/train-labels-idx1-ubyte'
```

The error only seems to be with the training-labels file; I tried redownloading the file, but that didn't fix it.

EDIT 2: As requested, here is the output of `ls -l /python/mnist-files`-

```
total 46156
-rw-r--r-- 1 inglorion inglorion 47040016 Jul 21  2000 train-images-idx3- 
ubyte
-rw-r--r-- 1 inglorion inglorion    60008 Jul 21  2000 train-labels-idx1- 
ubyte
-rw-r--r-- 1 inglorion inglorion   147970 Feb  8 22:43 wget-log
-rw-r--r-- 1 inglorion inglorion      682 Feb  9 14:40 wget-log.1
```

EDIT 3: Here is the output of `print(os.listdir('/python/mnist-files'))`:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/python/mnist-files'
```

I'm totally mystified- I *know* the directory exists! I can see it when I cd into `/python`!

Comment: Can you try putting your mnist data in the directory of your python-file? And then initiate MNIST like this `mndata = MNIST()`. Did you download _and unpack_ the files from [here](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/)? Can you add the outpyt of `ls -l /python/mnist-files`

Comment: @Jeppe- yes, I used the site you mentioned in your link. I _unzipped_ them as well, if that's what you mean.

Comment: @Jeppe- yes, I used the site you mentioned in your link. I _unzipped_ them as well, if that's what you mean.

Comment: Yes, unzip. :-P - Hm, your permissions/filesizes are the same as mine. What if you put a random file in the same directory - can you open it from python? Or perhaps run `print(os.listdir('/python/mnist-files'))`? Sorry, I'm just guessing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference between a **/** and **~**. By default,

```
os.dir('/')
```

will check at **`'/'`**. I guess your file python is in **`'~'`** i.e. your home directory.

You can try this:

```
from os.path import expanduser
home = expanduser("~")+'/python/mnist-files'
mndata = MNIST(home)
features,labels = mndata.load_training()
```

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: This was what I needed; I needed to write the file paths like '  /home/username/python/...'. Silly mistake caused by not knowing enough about file navigation. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

For me it helped to rename the file to `train-images.idx3-ubyte` instead of `train-images-idx3-ubyte` (the `-` after `images` got changed to a `.`).

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this code.

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('MNIST_data', validation_size=0)
```

I have executed the code and it works fine!! Hope you would find it helpful.